# How to avoid tampering of api response in spring boot

Tags: java, angular, spring, spring-boot

How to prevent response tampering for the reset api calls from Spring Boot.

I am using frontend as Angular and backend API calls are developed in Spring Boot.

After Successful login i am sending the response as like below

{
"loginStatus":"Success",
"token":"jwt token"
}

For Failure login i am sending the response as like below
{
"loginStatus":"Failure"
}

If it is success angular with check the loginStatus and it  will redirect to dashboard and now the issue is someone tampers the failure response and change to success . it is redirecting to dashboard.

How to prevent to redirect to dashboard page?

Comment: Your BE must not provide any (secured) data to an unauthenticated user i.e. a request without a valid JWT. Therefore an attacker would be able to reach an empty dashboard at best. I don't see a problem in the redirect, when the BE behaves correctly.

Comment: Thanks for reply. After Successful authentication only i am sending the Success response along with token  and there is no problem for other resources even it is redirected to dashboard because  i am using the token in every subsequent calls after login. But is should not redirect to dashboard page when my api sent failure response. attacker changing that failure response to success response and then it is redirecting to dashboard page. my front end is checking whether the login status is success and token available. then it will redirect to dashboard page

Comment: So you are trying to fix a UX problem for an attacker? In any case you can validate the token on the ui side as well.

Comment: No not from UX side. i am asking about  how to  fix this issue  from  backend (Spring Boot) or front end (Angular)

Comment: Doesn't the server respond with a 401 on your first request in the dashboard? Then your HttpInterceptor in angular should just redirect back to entry page. How is the repsonse modified? Is it a man in the middle attack?

Comment: @KiranReddyMandala: if your data APIs don't return any data without the token, then an attacker could make *their* client code show the dashboard, but it wouldn't be able to display any data, because they can't present the token and therefore won't get any data from the server. I fail to see the issue. All the attacker is doing is executing some local JS code that you already sent them, but they are not actually getting any new information.

Comment: @JoachimSauer .Yes  even though it  is redirecting to  dashboard it will not get any data from the server  as the token is not there. But without  successful authentication the attacker will see the static content available in the dashboard page. by modifying  the login response. how to prevent redirection to dashboard page and also how to prevent the response changing . how client knows  the attacker has change the  response.

Comment: @KiranReddyMandala: what static content? The attack can only see anything that code produces that you already sent them. If you sent them code that they should not be seeing, then you're doing it wrong. Don't send them code that you don't want them to have.